# PHP: access class method in callback function defined outside of class

Tags: php, class, callback

I have a class like

```
class Foo
{
  public function runWithCallback($custom_callback) {
    ...
    return call_user_func_array($custom_callback, [$arg_a, $arg_b]);
  }
  public function aHelperMethod($arg_a) {
    ...
  }
}
```

And when I use the class like

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->runWithCallback(function($arg_a, $arg_b) {
  ...
  // now I need to use helper method "aHelperMethod"
  $this->aHelperMethod($arg_c); // wrong code
  ...
});
```

Of course the above code does not work as `$this` makes no sense in that anonymous function.

Is it possible to do what I intended to? Thx.

Comment: you can access function like that `$foo->aHelperMethod()`

Comment: @BilalAhmed Thank you but I found it a bit "dirty". Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to @BilalAhmed 's comment, I found a "dirty" way of doing this:

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo->runWithCallback(function($arg_a, $arg_b) use ($foo) {
  ...
  // now I need to use helper method "aHelperMethod"
  $foo->aHelperMethod($arg_c); // wrong code
  ...
});
```